# Access violation at address in module "ANTserver.exe"

Tags: ant

I'm getting this error whenever a user attempts to connect to an ANT server...

Exception EAccessViolation raised in ReadRequest: Access violation at address 00071F40 in module 'ANTserver.exe'. Read of address 00000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being a corrupt login.xml.  Removed the file and it regenerated.